# Exception in defer callback: Error: No such template: autoform

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-autoform, simple-schema

Assuming I did everything like aldeed described [here](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#creating-a-custom-template) to create a custom form template. What did I forget or where is the mistake that the autoform tag is not present?

Actual html examle:

```
<template name="afType_talkBar">
  {{#autoform schema=Schema.Nachrichten id="sendMessageForm" type="insert"}}
  <fieldset class="clubChat__input">
    <div class="clubChat__message-bar">
        {{> afQuickField name='chatroomId'}}
        {{> afQuickField name='userName'}}
        <div class="form-group{{#if afFieldIsInvalid name='content'}} has-error{{/if}}">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                {{> afFieldInput name='content'}}
                <span class="input-group-addon">/each</span>
              </div>
              {{#if afFieldIsInvalid name='content'}}
              <span class="help-block">{{afFieldMessage name='content'}}</span>
              {{/if}}
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="{{_ 'chatAction.send'}}">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  {{/autoform}}
</template>
```

And the client side talkBar.js

```
import './talkBar.html';

// Import necessary js Packages
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';

import { Nachrichten } from '../../../api/nachrichten/nachrichten';
```

Bonus question. Inserting

```
Template.talkBar.helpers({
  nachrichtenCollection(){
    return Nachrichten;
  }
});
```

results into an **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'helpers' of undefined**

Looks like i'm missing something fundamental

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo Error instead of autoform it must be auto**F**orm

Correct code should look like this:

```
<template name="afType_talkBar">
  {{#autoForm schema=Schema.Nachrichten id="sendMessageForm" type="insert"}}
  <fieldset class="clubChat__input">
    <div class="clubChat__message-bar">
        {{> afQuickField name='chatroomId'}}
        {{> afQuickField name='userName'}}
        <div class="form-group{{#if afFieldIsInvalid name='content'}} has-error{{/if}}">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                {{> afFieldInput name='content'}}
                <span class="input-group-addon">/each</span>
              </div>
              {{#if afFieldIsInvalid name='content'}}
              <span class="help-block">{{afFieldMessage name='content'}}</span>
              {{/if}}
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="{{_ 'chatAction.send'}}">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  {{/autoForm}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your template name in helper definition is incorrect. The pattern is as below

`Template.Template_Name.helpers({});`

You have named incorrect template name. It must be as below,

`Template.afType_talkBar.helpers({});`

Also you used relative path while you are declaring a Collection in client JS file. You can use as below,

`import { nachrichten } from '/import/api/nachrichten/nachrichten.js'`;

This is much better convention because you may cut paste your js file anywhere else as per need and you may also create many js files and shuffle them in future, so the path will change as per your declaration.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that part. Wasn't awar that the template name refers to the helpers name. But still the autoform wont render.

Comment: What is the error? Check console if any thing appears. Update question with error details. I gave you your question's answer. If now the error is for autoform then that is another issue.

Comment: The error is/was the title of this question. It was indeed something fundamental. StackOverflow should install a typo bucket ;)